# Simple logistic regression with sklearn is generating an IndexError

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I am trying to generate a simple logistic regression model using a data set (CSV file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EbW22jvbnI0i8JnHC5TqiWemQpbV1zOd/view?usp=sharing). When trying to generate a classification plot, a traceback error is generated, and the reason has not been clear.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler 
Titanic_data = pd.read_csv('Titanic_noNAN.csv')
x = pd.DataFrame(Titanic_data['Age'])
y = pd.DataFrame(Titanic_data['Survived'])
xtrain, xtest, ytrain, ytest = train_test_split(x, y, test_size = 0.25, random_state = 0) 

sc_x = StandardScaler() 
xtrain = sc_x.fit_transform(xtrain)  
xtest = sc_x.transform(xtest)

from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap 
X_set, y_set = xtest, ytest

X1, X2 = np.meshgrid(np.arange(start = X_set[:, 0].min() - 1,  
stop = X_set[:, 0].max() + 1, step = 0.01), 
np.arange(start = X_set[:, 1].min() - 1,  
stop = X_set[:, 1].max() + 1, step = 0.01)) 

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-253-7e103a17b07d> in <module>
4 X1, X2 = np.meshgrid(np.arange(start = X_set[:, 0].min() - 1,  
5                                stop = X_set[:, 0].max() + 1, step = 0.01), 
----> 6                      np.arange(start = X_set[:, 1].min() - 1,  
7                                stop = X_set[:, 1].max() + 1, step = 0.01)) 
8 

IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1
```

Comment: Why all these `print` and `plot` statements, accuracies, and confusion matrices? Please notice that SO does not work by throwing [all our code as-is](https://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode/) in the question; at the very minimum, it is certainly expected that code that comes *after* the error (hence it's irrelevant to the issue since never executed) should be omitted (edited).

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to plot? X_set is your xtest predictions, which are Age values only, so X_set has only 1 column...